# Using group_by but return an array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I simply want to group cities by their state and from there have the array of the hash key (i.e. *State Name*) return an array of hash data pertaining to it's cities. Right now I have something like this:

```
City.all.group_by { |c| c.state.name }
```

Which will return:

```
{
  "Illinois": [# < City id: 3, name: "Chicago", state_id: 3 > ],
  "Texas": [# < City id: 2, name: "Houston", state_id: 2 > ],
  "California": [# < City id: 1, name: "Los Angeles", state_id: 1 > ],
  "New York": [# < City id: 4, name: "New York City", state_id: 4 > ]
}
```

Notice how it returns an array of rails objects. Instead I want to return an array of hashes with certain attributes, like their `id` and `name`.

Comment: Why do you want hashes instead of model instances?

Comment: @Stefan I want to later export the data to json.

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

Comment: Interesting. It'll group them the way I want too?

Comment: You still have to group the data yourself (in your controller). But you don't have to prepare a huge hash representing the entire JSON result. Instead you have a nice DSL to define your JSON (in your view).

Comment: Great. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the grouped values are Rails objects (your models) is due to the fact that you also start with these objects. You can use the [`attributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-attributes) method to retrieve the attributes of a model instance as a hash.

The following achieves the result you want:

```
City.all.group_by { |city| city.state.name }
  .transform_values { |cities| cities.map(&:attributes) }
```

If you only want specific attributes, use [`slice`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Core.html#method-i-slice) instead:

```
City.all.group_by { |city| city.state.name }
  .transform_values { |cities| cities.map { |city| city.slice(:id, :name) } }
```

Note that `slice` will return an [`ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) instance. Which mostly can be used in the same manner as a normal hash, but returns the same value for both `hash[:name]` and `hash['name']`. If you rather use a normal hash append a [`to_hash`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html#method-i-to_hash) call after the `slice` call.

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough for you

```
City.all.group_by { |c| c.state.name }.map {|k,v| [k, v.attributes] }.to_h
```

and to select only specified attributes do

```
v.attributes.slice(:name, :id)
```

Comment: You currently call `attributes` with an array as receiver, since each value is an array of cities. Resulting in a `NoMethodError`. Furthermore your `slice(:name, :id)` should be `slice('name', 'id')`, since `attributes` returns a hash where the keys are strings, not symbols.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest approach is to convert it into json object

```
City.all.as_json.group_by { |c| c.state.name }
```

this will fix the issue